# Getting or Copy value from one array of object to another array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

### Requirement :

I want result array based on unique `Device_MAC` key.

### Array 1

```
let Devices = [
  {
    Device_MAC: '44:6F:28:C1:2E:C0',
    Device_Model: 'Model 1',
    Date: '2021-4-27',
    Total: 66
  },
  {
    Device_MAC: '44:6F:28:C1:2E:C1',
    Device_Model: 'Model 1',
    Date: '2021-4-27',
    Total: 2
  }
]
```

### Array 2

```
let CompletedArray = [
    { Completed: 58, Device_MAC: '44:6F:28:C1:2E:C0' },
    { Completed: 2, Device_MAC: '44:6F:28:C1:2E:C1' }
  ]
```

### Array 3

```
let IncompletedArray = [{ Incompleted: 8, Device_MAC: '44:6F:28:C1:2E:C0' } ]
```

### Expected Array Result

```
let Result = [
  {
    Device_MAC: "44:6F:28:C1:2E:C0",
    Device_Model: "K Lite",
    Date: "2021-4-27",
    Total: 66,
    Complete: 58,
    Incomplete: 8,
  },
  {
    Device_MAC: "44:6F:28:C1:2E:C1",
    Device_Model: "K Lite",
    Date: "2021-4-27",
    Total: 2,
    Complete: 2,
    Incomplete: 0,
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const merge = (...arrays) => {
  const merged = {};
  arrays.forEach(a => a.forEach(item => 
    merged[item.Device_MAC] = Object.assign({Incompleted: 0, Completed: 0}, merged[item.Device_MAC], item)));
  return Object.values(merged);
};

// -----------
// Test

let Devices = [
  {
    Device_MAC: '44:6F:28:C1:2E:C0',
    Device_Model: 'Model 1',
    Date: '2021-4-27',
    Total: 66
  },
  {
    Device_MAC: '44:6F:28:C1:2E:C1',
    Device_Model: 'Model 1',
    Date: '2021-4-27',
    Total: 2
  }
]
let CompletedArray = [
    { Completed: 58, Device_MAC: '44:6F:28:C1:2E:C0' },
    { Completed: 2, Device_MAC: '44:6F:28:C1:2E:C1' }
  ]
let IncompletedArray = [{ Incompleted: 8, Device_MAC: '44:6F:28:C1:2E:C0' } ]

console.log(merge(Devices, CompletedArray, IncompletedArray));
```

Comment: I also want `Incompleted": 0`, in the second object in result as it doesn't match so.

Comment: Maybe instead of again demanding "I want", you could thank someone who tried to help you.

Comment: @Andy Sorry but i was in hurry to get result :)

Comment: @DhavalDarji I've updated the answer with "what you want".

Answer (score 0):

### So managed to get result like this

```
let cStatus = null,IncStatus  = null;

if (Devices.length) {
      Devices.forEach((device) => {
        cStatus = CompletedArray.length
          ? CompletedArray.find((obj) => {
              return obj.Device_MAC === device.Device_MAC ? obj.Completed : 0;
            })
          : 0;

        IncStatus = IncompletedArray.length
          ? IncompletedArray.find((obj) => {
              return obj.Device_MAC === device.Device_MAC ? obj.Incompleted : 0;
            })
          : 0;


        device.Completed = cStatus ? cStatus.Completed : 0;
        device.Incompleted = IncStatus ? IncStatus.Incompleted : 0;
      });
    }
```